# Better approach to re-draw colorized circles in HTML5 canvas, store values in array or recalculate color every time?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, colors

I got several objects where every one of them got priority value. Priority value can be between 1(lowest) to 200(higgest). 
 Every value is represented by a color, lowest value got green color `"rgba("0","255",0,1)";` and highest value got `"rgba("255","0",0,1)";`

I calculate color value by classic equation where every priority value determine different value(different color). So in the end i got possible chance of 200 different colors in range from green(0) to yellow(100) to red(200) based on priority.

My question is: When I'm redrawing on canvas all objects every 100ms. Is it better to calculate those values everytime to get wanted color or generate only ONCE in initialization function an array of 200 colors where value on `array[100]` will be color for object with 100 priority.

I expect there won't be like big a difference but still one of those approach must be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate once is the better option in almost every case (classically called a lookup table). Memory is cheaper than CPU cycles which means consumer hardware has plenty of RAM, but is always needing cycles.

In this case you are right, 200 colours every 100ms is insignificant even at full frame rate of 16.666...ms (60fps), but clients will have many applications/tabs/services running on the device and anything a programmer does to reduce CPU load will benefit the client.

There is also a added benefit that programmers tend to forget. CPU cycles require much more power than memory. For a single machine adding a few million cycles is nothing, but if every programmer wrote in a manner that reduced overall load the world wide savings in power are considerable. I am off to hug a tree now, hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is what i thought.

Answer (score 0):

from question i understand that you don't want calculation of color to affect your animation, use Web worker to run your calculation on separate thread [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) 
And one more thing Read all Style at one time and Write style at one time don't do Read/Write together because it may cause Layout Thrashing [Layout Thrashing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing?hl=en)

Comment: I actually want to know what is from performance perspective better. To allocate and hold 200 values in array which are generated only once, or to calculate one value every few miliseconds. Anyway, using web workers will definitely boost performance and make it smooth but even it's a good idea, it's not what i want to know. About Layout Thrasing, isn't that affecting CSS? Anyway thank you for your response.